# printing static message inside foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to print static message in the foreach loop section, but not getting any display message.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>       
        <td>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)*@
            @if (item.Status == 1)
            {
                @Html.Display("active")
            }
            else if (item.Status == 2)
            {
                @Html.Display("inactive")
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Instead of printing the `Status` value, I am trying to print as above. But under the `Status` column I am not getting any message.

Comment: is the Status an int or bool?

Comment: @Html.Display is expecting data in object and property form. Like @Html.Display(item.status). this razor helper will not work with static value of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Html.Raw` or special Razor tag `<text>`.

Here is a sample how to use them:

```
 <td>
      @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)*@
      @if (item.Status == 1)
      {
          @Html.Raw("active")
      }
      else if (item.Status == 2)
      {
          <text>inactive</text>
      }
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the Status is an integer

Do this instead:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>       
    <td>
        @if (item.Status == 1)
        {
            <span>Active</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>InActive</span>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
}
```